# Converting position with regarding anchorPoint?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, kobold2d

I have a sprite, which is added to `CCSpriteBatchNode`. Then I fix position of the sprite, changing anchor point the way so I can rotate sprite around that point.

Hierarchy is **sprite <- batchNode <- scene**

Basically sprite is moving but it's `.position` property is not changing. I need to get the real position of the sprite after transformations. So I tried to use

```
CGPoint p = sprite.position;
p = [sprite convertToWorldSpace:p];
```

However, position is not matching to the sprite's position which I see in the scene.

Answer (score 0):

Sprite position is a point at the middle of the CCSprite(by default). Changing the anchor point moves the sprite such that the point moves with respect to the sprite but remains same with respect to the world space. For example, changing the anchor point of a sprite(say square) to ccp(0,0) will move the square so that its bottom left vertex will come at the position where the square's center point was initially. So while the square may seem to be "repositioned" ,its position (property) stays the same(unaffected by change in anchor point) unless specifically changed.

**EDIT**

If by real position of the sprite, you mean its mid point after its anchor point has been changed then it can be calculated by taking into account the two transformations that have been applied on it i.e. Translation and Rotation.

First we take care of **Translation**:

Your sprite has moved by:

```
CGPoint translation;
translation.x =  sprite.contentSize.width x (0.5 - sprite.anchorPoint.x);
translation.y =  sprite.contentSize.height x (0.5 - sprite.anchorPoint.y);
```

Now we accomodate for change in **Rotation**

Converting "translation" point into polar coordinates we get

```
#define RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(radians) ((radians) * (180.0 / M_PI))
r = ccpDistance(translation,ccp(0,0));
ø = RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(atan2(translation.x,translation.y)); //i take x/y here as i want the CW angle from y axis.
```

If you rotated your sprite by "D" degrees:

```
 ø = ø + D;
 CGPoint transPositionAfterRotation = ccp(r * cos(ø),r * sin(ø) );

CGPoint realPosition =  ccp(sprite.position.x + transPositionAfterRotation.x, sprite.position.y +transPositionAfterRotation.y)
```

Comment: This doesn't really work. It doesn't consider rotation(mentioned in my question), which also affects position. The anchor point in my case is not a mid point but far away from the sprite.

Comment: what do you mean by the "real position" of the sprite?

Comment: I mean position after applying rotation.

Comment: position, based on anchor point, position and applied rotation.

Comment: 1. rcos/rsin? 2. atan2 take 2 parameters 3. I think with cocos2D all those calculations come for free, but not sure which convert functions to use.

Comment: i rushed through the answer, thought you'd figure out rcosø as r * cos(ø) , have edited my answer though. The calculations can be put inside a function and used.